# Medicare A for 5 years; how to now sign up for B

Tags: medicare

I started Medicare A in 2013 when I turned 65. In the years since, I have remained on my husband's employer group insurance, so did not need Medicare B. Although he still has this insurance, I would like to change to Medicare B. It's not clear how I do this so that Medicare B will begin Jan. 1, 2019 to coincide with my other insurance ending Dec. 31, 2018.

Do I qualify for special enrollment? If so, how do I do this? The group insurance deadline is Nov. 16, 2018, so I need to know soon whether I can not re-enroll and change to Medicare B.

Answer (score 1):

You can enroll in Medicare at their web site (MEDICARE.GOV) or you can contact them at 800-MEDICARE

BTW, if you're considering a  Part B supplemental plan, the Medigap Plan F is a popular choice that offers more coverage than the other choices.  There is a high-deductible Plan F (called F*)  that offers the same benefits as the standard Plan F but costs approximately 3/4 less (depending on age and if medically underwritten).

If you have a low number of claims, you'll save a lot on the annual cost.  And even if it hits the fan, the total cost for the year will be less on the F* plan since the deductible plus annual cost for the F* plan is less than the annual cost of the F plan.

Comment: You could also go to your local Social Security office and sign up there. Just like signing up for Part A. Just tell them you no longer want to be covered by your spouse's insurance and want to enroll in Part B. (You'll also have to decide then on Part D as well, I believe.)

Comment: You can save a trip an enroll online as well.